# Why no error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have recently switched from a c# team to a vb.net team. One of the things I have not been able to find an answer to is the differences in compile error / options. Let me explain.

In C# i will, using default settings, get a compile time error when trying to pass in an invalid type to a templated class like below. Here I create an Animal with a string type and afterwards I pass in a datetime which results in an compile error.

```
 IAnimal<string> animal = new Animal<string>();
 animal.SetTrainer(DateTime.Now);
```

I know I will get the same compile time error in vb.net with "Option Strict". There is, however, a lot of legacy (VB) code in the same file that will not compile with "Option Strict". What options do I have. Im thinking this:

1. Switch to "Option Strict" and fix all errors. Will take some time and may break working code.
2. Maybe there is an alternate that will ensure compile time check of generics. After all generics are rather new so maybe there is a way of always enforcing this.
3. ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double click your Project -> My Project.

Goto Compile and look for Warningconfiguration

Now you can change some settings.

- Implicit cast
- Late Binding

don't make them errors but warnings.

That won't make compile time errors but you can at least see some warnings.

Another solution would be to make your class a partial class and move your code to a new file. You can set Option Strict / Option Explicit on a per file basis.

Comment: +1 Highly agree. But if you mind about this I would **turn on Option Strict at project level** and I'd add **Option Strict Off to each file** won't compile without it. Step by step you'll then work to refactor existing code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this. I will discuss it with my team

Comment: @Adriano, +1 - that's probably the best solution.

Comment: +1 Adriano. Otherwise newly-added files would be Option Strict Off by default, and that would be bad. Also change the visual studio settings so that Option Strict is On by default in new projects.

Answer (score 3):

> Switch to "Option Strict" and fix all errors. Will take some time and may break working code.

Yes, do that. It will help you remain sanity.

Most errors that will pop up are probably simple casting issues, which are easy to fix (a `CInt` here, a `ToString()` there...).

You don't have to fix your whole solution or project at once, since you can enable `Option Strict On` at file level. Make it a good habbit to fix every file as you have to touch it.

This will not always be possibly, but you can also just move code that heavily relies on `Option Strict On` (e.g. `COM` stuff) to another file without breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree that "Option Strict" is the way to go. Now I just have to persuade my team :-)